# Combine the users of 2 similar APP Store apps

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am currently using a Free & paid version of an app and want to change to a freemium scheme. Basically:

**Before:**

- Free version with less features that entices to buy the paid
- Paid version with more features

**After:**

- Just the free app but with multiple in app purchases of various features.

(I'd also like to automatically give my paid users the in app purchase that gives them the functionality they already paid for)

I cant seem to find any documentation pertaining to this scenario.

I have considered making the paid V free and have the app search for older version saved files and auto enable the feature. But if I do this Im loosing the 80K users that use the free version. I could have the free version display a note to download the other version, which is now free. All though I would be like to give my loyal free app users the same features they already had, since one of the features that was free will probably be paid now.

**Posible workaround?**

1. Convert the Free version into the new version with in app purchases, this way we capture the larges user base automatically.
2. App looks for old files and if so enable feature that was once free. So old free users have the same functionally the've always had.
3. Upgrade paid version to generate a code that the user can enter in the new version and enable extra features. (would probably need to setup a server for this..)

This somewhat works but someone might think of a cleaner way to do this...

BTW why was I voted down -2? Is this question out of scope of what stackoverflow is for ir what? A note to know why would be decent..

Comment: It's a decent question, but you're asking more about a business model than a specific coding issue, so this is probably off topic for this site. There's a proposal for an [App Store](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) site that might be able to host questions like this.

Comment: many thanks Brad. I'll look around for a site to relocate this question:)

Comment: One place I might recommend is the iPhone Software Business mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb .  It's a little quieter than it used to be, but there have been many good discussions of iOS-related business issues there. You might even find something like this in the archives there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

1. Upgrade both apps to store keys in keychain to identify if they were installed previously. (2 diferent keys one for each)
2. Give time for the major part of your user base to upgrade to versio that creates the keys.
3. Make free app into "universal app" with all features that were available in free and paid as im app purchases. If key is found for free or paid. In app purchases are enabled automatically to provide the respective  fetures 
   the user already had in old versions.
4. Upgrade paid to instruct users to download the universal version and that there features will be enabled automatically.
5. Universal displays a popup like "if you are missing a feature you already had please contact..." if user makes contact, send them a code to activate features through an app interface. (no need to setup a verification syste
   As most people will not take the time to do it to try and get a free upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

Can only update one app, you could update the paid one, make it free and add the in app purchases in that version.

There is no way to give the already paid user the IAP for free, unless you have a server which knows which user bought what.
If you do not have this then there is no secure way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, maybe some sort of work around? (I added more info up top)

Comment: Not really, best way to keep all user satisfied is to add the IAP in the free version and keep the paid full version update as well. This is the only way to do this correctly. There is just no way to give all the user of you paid app the IAPs for free.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's app store (currently) does not support any way to combine apps or transfer IAPs between apps or accounts.

Your only choice, if you want to support both sets of customers, may be to continue to support and build two versions of the app, one free with IAP, one paid.

Comment: OK, It Cant be done directly, Any ideas for a workaround?